# Read Barcode in an WP8.1 app with ZXing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, barcode, zxing

Im currently writing my first app for WP8.1. The app just need to scan a barcode.

```
        public async void ScanBarcodeAsync(Windows.Storage.StorageFile Afile)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitmap;
        BitmapDecoder decoder;

        using (IRandomAccessStream str = await Afile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(str);
            bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(decoder.PixelWidth),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(decoder.PixelHeight));
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(str);
        }

        ZXing.BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        /*reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new ZXing.BarcodeFormat[]
        {
            ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
            ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_39
        };*/
        reader.Options.TryHarder = true;
        reader.AutoRotate = true;

        var results = reader.Decode(bitmap);
        if (results != null)
        {
            edtBarcode.Text = results.Text; 
        }
        else
        {
            edtBarcode.Text = "Error";
        }
    }
```

The file for this method is created this way

```
    async void StartCapture()
    {
        var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
        settings.PhotoCaptureSource = Windows.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
        settings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
        settings.AudioDeviceId = string.Empty;
        settings.VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id;

        captureManager = new MediaCapture();    //Define MediaCapture object  
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync(settings);   //Initialize MediaCapture and 
        var focusSettings = new FocusSettings();
        focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.Macro;
        focusSettings.Mode = FocusMode.Auto;
        focusSettings.WaitForFocus = true;
        focusSettings.DisableDriverFallback = false;

        captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
        captureManager.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
        capturePreview.Source = captureManager;   //Start preiving on CaptureElement  



        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();  //Start camera capturing   
    }
    async private void Capture_Photo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create JPEG image Encoding format for storing image in JPEG type  
        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        // create storage file in local app storage  
        if (ImageIndex > 0)
        {
            StorageFile delFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Photo" + Convert.ToString(ImageIndex - 1) + ".jpg");
            await delFile.DeleteAsync();
        }
        file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Photo" + Convert.ToString(ImageIndex++) + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        // take photo and store it on file location.  
        await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);
        //// create storage file in Picture Library  
        //StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Photo.jpg",CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);  
        // Get photo as a BitmapImage using storage file path.  

        bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
        bmpImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(file.Path);

        ImageTaken = true;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

I dont get an error running this code. But the result from ZXing is always null. The ScanBarcodeAsync-Function is directly run after taking the picture. The image the app takes is not sharp. Can this cause the problem?

Im happy to get any suggestions to solve my problem.

Comment: Try using a clearer barcode image to check if the ZXing can decode or not. Noisy image may cause this problem.

Comment: @ssakash Thank you for your tip! I will test it soon.

Comment: There is a more simpler QR code reader implementation for windows phone by Jeff Wilcox. Have a look at that too. That implementation uses ZXing. http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/wpqr-control/

Comment: @ssakash This implementation looks much better. Thanks for it, too! :) I will have a look, how I can use this for Barcodes and not QR-Codes.